# SoundcloudAPI Wrapper iOS5 authentication errors

Tags: objective-c, ios5, soundcloud, audio

I'm trying to prototype an app which utilizes Soundcloud's API endpoints, and integrates the cocoa-api-wrapper for cocoa and cocoa touch projects.

The problem I'm having revolves around getting my application to authenticate.  I display the login view to the user, and after they input their credentials, try and handle the redirect URL using a method implementation in my app delegate.

When I trace the series of calls throughout MyApp->Soundcloud API -> Oauth2Library during debugging, I can see that soundcloud accepts the credentials, and passes back the authorization_code which I then understand I'm supposed to use to request a session authentication token.

However when 'handleOpenURL' (in my AppDelegate) gets called, it fails to process the redirect and returns a 401 error whenever I try to gather user data (such as sending a call to `[scAPI meWithContext:@"userInfo"]`).

I've absolutely scoured these forums, and cannot seem to find the answer to my problem.  I did however, stumble upon [something](http://groups.google.com/group/soundcloudapi/browse_thread/thread/6e418460d098cb20/ad12882b13e49dbe?lnk=gst&q=ios%205#ad12882b13e49dbe) that I think might be part of the case on the google groups forums for Soundcloud API support.

Another API user encounters a 401 response code (unauthorized), and  describes a difference in the way the oauth2 library manages the authorized header field in the redirect response from SoundCloud between iOS 4 and iOS 5, and I am thinking this may be part of the issue.

The 401 response code has a localized description of `NXOAuth2HTTPErrorDomain`, and also writes the message `[NXOAuth2PostBodyStream open] Stream has been reopened after close` to NSLog.

I can provide more information if need be.  I'm also using charles to debug the HTTPS calls to Soundcloud, and am certain the request is being sent to the correct destination.

Any help / feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: The cocoa-api-wrapper is not supported anymore. You should use the new [CocoaSoundCloudAPI](https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI). To get started have a look at the [Demo](https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudDemo).

Comment: Thanks Tobias! That was going to be my next approach.  Originally, I favored the cocoa wrapper because it had streaming classes built in, but I could always use the 'bare bones' concepts from them and write my own I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tobias mentioned, the cocoa-api-wrapper is not supported anymore. I ran into the same problem, and since I needed streaming functionality as well, [I forked the CocoaSoundCloudAPI to add streaming support from the cocoa-api-wrapper](https://github.com/iliaskarim/CocoaSoundCloudAPI).

Comment: Very cool. I've gotten past the authentication part by using the new CocoaSoundCloudAPI.  I've been messing around with the streaming portion of the old wrapper and am getting a 'BadPropertyError' from my PropertyChangedListener after I receive the first part of a byte stream, because it somehow thinks my sampleRate is set to 0.

Comment: I hope my fork might work for you. I published it in my app [SoundCrate](http://www.soundcrate.it/). Right now we are preparing a new version of our app, though, which we wrote our own streaming support for, since we found a couple minor glitches in the cocoa-api-wrapper, like how it would not transition smoothly between consecutive tracks

Comment: too bad SoundCloud isn't supporting streaming in their SDK anymore, apparently due to legal issues about the code making it trivial to download tracks that are only meant to be streamed :(

Comment: Very cool. I'll add it as a submodule to a rendition of the same project and see what I can muster.  A lot of my problems most-likely arose b/c I was trying to convert the SCAudioStream lib to use ARC.  The combination of my OAuth2Account didReceiveData and the AudioFileStream property change listener callbacks resulted in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I went to parse.  That's a bummer that they aren't moving forward with that part of the SDK -_-